# Rails 5, updating specific form fields in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, controller, ruby-on-rails-5, simple-form

I have admin account to edit some posts from other users, mostly typo stuff. When I use the controller below, it updates user_id since I get that from current_user (admin in my case), so it updates the post with my account, and post looks like submitted by me. it overwrites actual user id.

```
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.update(post_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @post }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

---

btw this is my _form.html.erb which is used both for new and edit.

```
<%= simple_form_for(@post) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

    <%= f.input :user_id, input_html: { value: current_user.id }, as: :hidden  %>
    <%= f.input :title, required: true, autofocus: true, placeholder: "Post title: *", label: false, input_html: { maxlength: 140, size: 40 } %>
    <%= f.input :link, required: true, placeholder: "Post link: *", label: false, input_html: { maxlength: 300, size: 40 } %>
    <%= f.input :description, placeholder: "Summary of the Post", label: false, input_html: { maxlength: 600, :rows => 5 } %>

    <%= f.button :submit, "Post" %>
<% end %>
```

and my schema

```
  create_table "posts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.string "link"
    t.text "description"
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.string "slug"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["slug"], name: "index_posts_on_slug"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_posts_on_user_id"
  end
```

---

**How can I skip updating user_id?** I tried to code below just to define the fields I wanted to update, but it doesn't work. Thank you

```
if @post.update(post_params[:title, :link, :description])
```

Comment: or `input_html: { value: @post.user_id.empty? ? current_user.id : @post.user_id }`

Comment: it gives "undefined method `user_id' for nil:NilClass" error since it is not a thing for new post I believe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this instead, thanks!

```
@post.title = post_params[:title]
@post.link = post_params[:link]
@post.description = post_params[:description]
```

Put this before `respond do` and replace `if @post.update(post_params)` to `if @post.save`

Comment: where does it actually go? It can't go into @post.update("here") and if we define before the update line, how do we assign this into update? Thank you

Comment: oh it worked! but why .save would do since we are actually updating?

Comment: .save - if the record is new, a new record gets created in the database, otherwise the existing record gets updated. Rails figures this out by checking if the record that calls .save already exist in the the database or not. Check out documentation here! https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/save%21